# Is there a debian/ubuntu policy on softlinking things to another location in opt once they're installed?

Tags: packaging, debian, policy

Is there a debian/ubuntu policy on softlinking things to another location in opt once they're installed properly in usr/share or usr/lib?

Here's a simple example:
Packaging up dnsenum.  It's a REALLY simple package (4 files).
A perl script, two wordlists, and a readme.

So from what I gather:
The wordlists should go in usr/share/dnsenum/*
The perl script itself would go in usr/lib/dnsenum/
The readme would go in usr/share/doc/dnsenum/

Add a wrapper bash script that goes in bin and just passes arguments to dnsenum.pl.

The question is this:

If there are various tools that provide wordlists or some other shared resource, is there a policy on linking all the wordlists from different packages in to /opt/wordlists/ ?

It seems like the "right" thing to do respecting the directory structure while still making things convenient.

Comment: Are you aware of any packages which install anything in `/opt/`? FHS does not seem to prohibit this (http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES) but I never saw the package manager to install anything in `/opt`. I always thought this directory is for manually installed "add-on application software packages"

Comment: @Sergey Yeah, I know /opt is sort of a free-for-all and Ubuntu policy is third party software installed through software center goes there.  That's why I asked (Ubu policy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu follows the FHS. Ubuntu packages install everything into `/usr/`. Runtime data can live in `/var/lib/PACKAGENAME`, and some critical early-boot things that live outside `/usr`, in `/bin`, `/lib`, etc.

So, your wordlists would go into `/usr/share/dnsenum`, yes. The script would probably just go into `/usr/bin`, and the documentation would go into `/usr/share/doc/dnsenum`.

Ubuntu doesn't put anything in `/opt`. However, third party applications distributed through the software centre have *everything* in `/opt`, to keep them separated from the rest of the system. These are not part of the distribution.

There's nothing special about data that's shared between packages, assuming it's still owned by a single package, depended on, by the others.

An example for word lists is `/usr/share/dict/words`, provided by `dictionaries-common`.